# How to initialize environment variable in a Spring-Java integration test using Cucumber?

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, integration-testing

I added the following environment variable to my project's properties file (src/test/resources/application.properties):

```
#variables
  limit=5
```

And I want to develop an integration test but it always goes wrong because the value of my limit variable is 0 instead of 5 (which was the value I set in properties). I tried using @SpringBootTest and @TestPropertySource but I was unsuccessful, the variable remains as zero:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"limit=5"})
@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:project/feature/list" }, plugin = {"pretty" }, monochrome = true)
public class RunCucumberTestIT {

}

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"limit=5"})
@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:project/feature/list" }, plugin = {"pretty" }, monochrome = true)
public class RunCucumberTestIT {

}
```

Comment: Mhh, `@SpringBootTest(properties = {"limit=5"})` should be fine, strange that it doesn't work. Can you also try `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")`?

Comment: Hello, I tried this: @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties", properties = {"limit = 5"}) but the variable remains as zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who tried to help. I will share how I managed to solve it, I didn't actually need to use `@TestPropertySource` or `@SpringBootTest`, I just changed the way my variable was declared within the service that my integrated test calls.

Before:

```
@Value("${limit}")
private static int dateFilterLimit;
```

After:

```
@Value("${limit:5}")
private int dateFilterLimit;
```

Thus, if the test fails to see what is declared in the properties, the value 5 is set within the variable. For the rest of the code, the variable in properties remains:

```
#variables
limit=5
```

And the configuration class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:project/feature/list" }, plugin = {"pretty" }, monochrome = true)
public class RunCucumberTestIT {

}
```

Comment: You've made the problem go away by setting a default. But it seems your application isn't reading from the properties file. That's not the expected behavior. Are you sure you fixed the problem?

Comment: I agree with you. But my cucumber.version is 4.7.2 so I cannot follow the suggestion of friend M.P. Korstanje

Comment: Ah. Put the spring boot test annotation on a single class with step definitions in it. It is silly but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make Cucumber aware of your Spring application context configuration by annotating the JUnit runner class. However Cucumber integrates with multiple testing frameworks and has it's own CLI. As a result annotating the JUnit runner class will not always work (e.g. when the CLI).

So to do this [you can annotate a configuration class on your glue path with @CucumberContextConfiguration](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/spring#configuring-the-test-application-context) and with `@SpringBootTest`.

With the latest version of Cucumber (v6.9.0) this should work:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

```java
package com.example.app;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:project/feature/list" }, plugin = {"pretty" }, monochrome = true)
public class RunCucumberTestIT {

}
```

```java
package com.example.app;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"limit=5"})
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {

}
```

Note: the package of the configuration class should be on the glue path. When not defined it defaults to the package of the runner class.